# maven release:perform failed

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to understand the maven-release-plugin (version 2.0, CVS).
The **release-prepare** works well. 
But I do not understand why the **release-perform** don't work?? I've tested the deploy feature and I can deploy artifacts to the remote repo without any exceptions.

```
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] Failed to configure plugin parameters for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4
[INFO] check that the following section of the pom.xml is present and correct:
[INFO] <distributionManagement>
[INFO]   <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
[INFO]   <repository>
[INFO]     <id>repo</id>
[INFO]     <name>Repository Name</name>
[INFO]     <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
[INFO]   </repository>
[INFO]   <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
[INFO]   <snapshotRepository>
[INFO]     <id>repo</id>
[INFO]     <name>Repository Name</name>
[INFO]     <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
[INFO]   </snapshotRepository>
[INFO] </distributionManagement>
[INFO]
[INFO] Cause: Class 'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository' cannot be instantiated
[INFO] Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
```

Comment: that's going to be difficult to answer here, maybe you could give this thread a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810957/maven-release-plugin-war-stories

Comment: what configuration have you added for the release plugin? What version of the release plugin are you using? What version of Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve the issue. I tried to make the release from the my child POM. The repository url specified in the parent POM. But why my child POM didn't inherit it...

Comment: So you mean the reference to the git repository should be in the children POMs as well?

Answer (score 7):

First you should make sure that you have configured the `<distributionManagement>` in the right way, as suggested by the error itself. Then try running the `release:prepare` goal with specifying `-Dresume=false` in the command line like this:

```
$ mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false
```

Upon successful completion, run the `release:perform` goal again, the error should hopefully disappear.

Comment: What does `-Dresume=false` mean?